# Generate from array sequential executions with deferreds (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

Is there any mean to make this more elegant using other solutions (jquery is fine)?

Important in my case is that respective executions are only triggered if the previous ones have been terminated.

```js
seqExe(["item one", "item two", "item three", "item four", "item five"])

function seqExe(corpus) {
    var i = -1,
        len = corpus.length,
        defer = jQuery.Deferred(),
        promise = defer.promise();

    while(++i < len) {
        promise = promise.then((function(item) {
            return function() {
                console.log(item);
                return foo(item);
            }
        }).call(this, corpus[i]));
    }

    promise.then(function() {
        console.log("Done");
    }, function() {
        console.error("Failed");
    });

    return defer.resolve();
}

function foo(item) {
    var defer = jQuery.Deferred();
    window.setTimeout(
        function() {
            defer.resolve()
            console.log(item);
        }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);

    return defer.promise();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Supposed output should be:

```
item one
item one
item two
item two
item three
item three
item four
item four
item five
item five
Done
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an ideal candidate for using `reduce`. Furthermore your initial promise -- which you want to resolve immediately -- can be just `$.when()`, and will become the start value of the `reduce` call:

```js
seqExe(["item one", "item two", "item three", "item four", "item five"])

function seqExe(corpus) {
    return corpus.reduce(function (p, item) {
        return p.then(function () {
            console.log(item + ' pending');
            return foo(item);
        });
    }, $.when())
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Done");
    }, function(){
        console.log("Failed");
    });
}

function foo(item) {
    var defer = new $.Deferred();
    window.setTimeout(
        function() {
            defer.resolve()
            console.log(item + ' resolved');
        }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
    return defer.promise();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Note that in some jQuery versions (I see this in 2.1.1) the `then` callbacks are executed synchronously, which would give the wrong output order. This is fixed in jQuery 3 (I tried 3.1.1, which I also linked to in the above snippet).

Here is how you would do it with native ES6 promises:

```js
seqExe(["item one", "item two", "item three", "item four", "item five"])

function seqExe(corpus) {
    return corpus.reduce(function (p, item) {
        return p.then(function () {
            console.log(item + ' pending');
            return foo(item);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve())
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Done");
    }, function(){
        console.log("Failed");
    });
}

function foo(item) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
            console.debug(item + ' resolved');
        }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*then callbacks are executed synchronously, which would give the wrong output order.*"? That only could happen on already-fulfilled promises, i.e. `$.when()`, but everything after the first `foo()` call is chained.

Comment: @Bergi, I meant that if in the snippet I posted, I linked to jQuery version 2.1.1 instead of 3.1.1, the order of the output changed. NB: I made a correction now, because I had first moved the second console.log, and forgot to put it back in place (after resolve).

Comment: Ah, that. Right, you'd have to place the `console.debug` in front of the `deferred.resolve()` call for that.

Comment: Indeed, it was what I tried before I realised it was a peculiar behaviour of jQuery 2.